# Receiving notifications with dropbox API

Tags: javascript, angular, dropbox-api

We are building a dropbox interface with angular 5 for a school assignment.
I'm trying to add a webhook to make the file list refresh everytime there is some kind of change to a file/folder.
I'm stuck at Receiving notifications, and I have no idea how to proceed.
A notification request is an HTTP POST request with a JSON body.

This is what I came up with.

```
getUpdates() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken);
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  headers.append('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
  return this.http.post('https://url/webhook', null, { headers })
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
```

Error I'm getting:

> "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

Some things I'm missing and don't really understand:
Keeping track of each user's OAuth access token and their latest cursor. (latest cursor?)
Every notification request will include a header called **X-Dropbox-Signature** that includes an **HMAC-SHA256 signature of the request body**, using your app secret as the signing key.

Comment: See [This](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors)

Comment: You'll need to do some research on CORS and make sure your webhook endpoint is configured correctly.

Comment: Is 'https://url/webhook' supposed to be the URL where you want to be notified about changes in the Dropbox accounts of your users? If so, note that you're not supposed to be crafting these HTTPS requests yourself. The notifications come from Dropbox itself. Please review the documentation for more information: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks